# IPtables 'nat' filter problems

Tags: wireless, debian

I'm trying to do some wireless stuff on my raspberry pi which is running Raspian (Debian 8).

However, I get this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
Healing 192.168.0.14
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I've tried apt upgrade and update, but they did nothing.

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a system update a new kernel, including the elf binaries, were installed. But the new kernel was just not using it yet.

That's the problem. After reboot the new kernel is in use and everything works fine.

I've got the solution from this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=153219&p=1004702)

> Actually that message looks like the one you get when you have done a
>   kernel upgrade, but haven't rebooted to start using the new kernel.
>
> It is saying that it can't find the kernel modules (drivers) that
>   match your currently running kernel. This is because the upgrade has
>   removed them and put in ones for the new kernel.
>
> A reboot is all that should be needed

.